Vector list changing after assigning to a class
I am creating instances of the polynomial class using vectors.
I create a vector supposedly containing 10 1's and assign it to a polynomial instance of the polynomial class according to the code below:
class polynomial10 {
public:
    vector <double> coef;
    polynomial10( vector <double>& c );
    double evaluate(double x);
    polynomial10 adiciona(polynomial10 p);
};

polynomial10::polynomial10( vector<double>& c) : coef(c) {};
    double polynomial10::evaluate (double x) {
    double t = coef.size();
    double eval = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        eval += coef[i]*pow(x,i+1); 
    }
    return eval;
}

polynomial10 polynomial10::adiciona (polynomial10 p) {
    int t = sizeof(coef);
    int t2= sizeof(p.coef);
    if (t>=t2) {
        vector<double> coef_r(t,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            if (i<=t2) {
                coef_r[i] += coef[i]+p.coef[i];
        }
        else {
            coef_r[i] += coef[i];
        }
    }
    polynomial10 p3(coef_r);
    return p3;
    }
    else {
        vector<double> coef_r(t2,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < t2; i++) {
            if (i<=t) {
                coef_r[i] += coef[i]+p.coef[i];
            }
            else {
                coef_r[i] += p.coef[i];
            }
        }
    polynomial10 p3(coef_r);
    return p3;
    }
}
int main() {
    vector<double> c1(10,1);
    polynomial10 p1(c1);
    vector<double> c2(10,2);
    polynomial10 p2(c2);
    double um = p1.evaluate(2);
    cout << um << endl;
    polynomial10 p3 = p1.adiciona(p2);
    double tres = p3.evaluate(1);
    cout << tres << endl;
    int t = sizeof(c1);
    for (int i =0; i<t;i++) {
        //cout << p1.coef[i] << endl;
        cout << c1[i] << endl;
    }

What's happening is that when i instantiate the list of 10 1's in fact it creates a list of 12 elements in which the last 2 are virtually zero, something like 1e-303.
Second when I assign this vector to the polynomial class the second zero value, the 12th value in the list of 1's becomes two, so I am creating a 12th order polynomial instead of a 10th order one, in which the 12th element is 2, instead of 0.
Then when I apply the evaluate function to evaluate its value in different x values it gets the wrong answer.
So why does the creation of the 10 1's is in fact composed of 12 values and why when I assign it to the class it generates a number 2 in the 12th position out of the blue?
How can I work around this issue?

int t = sizeof(coef); -- Why are you using sizeof?  Are you aware of what sizeof does?  The correct function to use is std::size() or the vector member function size().  What's strange is that you used it here: double t = coef.size();, but for some reason, resorted to using sizeof in other places.

I am not aware what it does, anyway you got it and solved the issue, now it seems to be working fine. What's sizeof about?

The sizeof is a compile-time constant that returns the size of the type in bytes.  It does not return the number of entries.  If you want proof of this, see this

@ArthurRamosPiotto What does sizeof do?
